# Did any Prime Ministers go on strike before?

Tags: protests, comparative-politics, prime-minister, iceland

https://edition.cnn.com/2023/10/23/europe/iceland-women-strike-scli-intl/index.html

> Women across Iceland – including the prime minister – will go on strike Tuesday as part of a campaign pushing for greater gender equality in the country.
>
> The strike, which is known as the “Women’s Day Off” or “Kvennafrí” in Icelandic, hopes to raise awareness about the “systemic” wage discrimination and gender-based violence faced by women in Iceland, according to organizers.
>
> Icelandic Prime Minister Katrín Jakobsdóttir told Icelandic news site Iceland Monitor on Friday that she will not work on the strike day and expects other female members of government to do the same “in solidarity with Icelandic women.”

Are there other examples where PMs (in any country) have gone on strike in solidarity with some part of the population doing the same, or even for other reasons?

Comment: Iceland is a bit of a special case, I think, since it is very sparsely populated and has a smaller population overall than most cities. The prime minister can probably afford to take a day off. I feel like that would be less practical with a country like the USA or China—even when they are "on vacation" (and some leaders have spent a lot of time in this state), they are nonetheless actually working a fair amount daily, taking calls and having briefings and so forth.